# Seperate ID's resulted from while query

Tags: php

I have a query that returns all information from a specific user in a table. This user can have multiple records in the table and they're uniquely identified by an `ID` column.

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = '$UserID'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        echo $row['ID'];
    }
```

This returns 949596 which are the three ID's 94, 95 and 96 in the DB. How can I separate that result and have each ID in a variable?

To get the last ID I can do:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            $AssignedID = $row['ID'];
        }

echo $AssignedID;
```

This would result in 96 which is the last assigned ID. Unfortunately it's not enough as I need all of them in order to allow the end user to update their objects through a page. This all depends on the ID's

I tried working with an array like someone suggested, but just can't seem to get it working.

Anyone who could help me?

Comment: `echo $row['ID'] . '<br />';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just put all of them in a array() and print them out...

```
$ids = array();
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UserID = '$UserID'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        $ids[] = $row['ID'];
    }
print_r($ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
echo $row['ID'];
```

to

```
$val =  $row['ID'];
```

on each iteration $val will have new value in it.